# Handle Click event of button of mainActivity in all fragment in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I want to handle click event of mainactivity's button in all fragment so what i can do for that.?

i have one button in mainactivity and i want to handle click event of that button in different fragment for different operation

Comment: Put your code..

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public Button button;

button= (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button);

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
             // Different Operation Code
       }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class that implements the OnClickListener. Then you set your listener class to the button, so you can manage what you want to do in your own listener class. You can check all that you need and do the consequent action.

Comment: Do you have any reference link.?

Comment: No, but it's simple. Create a class MyButtonListener that implements OnClickListener. Then on your button: button,setActionListener(myButtonListener). The idea is that on your listener you can override the onclick method wicht receives  the View object, and that object contains the information you will need to decide what you want to do. Try it and debug it and you will see that it's simple.